# Can not spawn function on remote node with spawn(Node, Fun) in erlang

Tags: erlang, distributed

experimenting with distributed erlang, here's what I have:

```
 loop()->
    receive {From, ping} ->
            io:format("received ping from ~p~n", [From]),
            From ! pong,
            loop();
        {From, Fun} when is_function(Fun) ->
            io:format("executing function ~p received from ~p~n", [Fun, From]),
            From ! Fun(),
            loop()
    end.

    test_remote_node_can_execute_sent_clojure()->
        Pid = spawn(trecias, fun([])-> loop() end),
        Pid ! {self(), fun()-> erlang:nodes() end},
        receive Result -> 
            Result = [node()]
        after 300 ->
                  timeout
        end.
```

getting: `Can not start erlang:apply,[#Fun<tests.1.123107452>,[]] on trecias`

node I execute the test on runs on the same machine as the node 'trecias'. Both nodes can load same code.

Any ideas what is amiss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `spawn` call, you've specified the node name as `trecias`, but you need to specify the full node name including the hostname, e.g. `trecias@localhost`.

Also, the function you pass to `spawn/2` must take zero arguments, but the one in the code above takes one argument (and crashes if that argument isn't the empty list).  Write it as `fun() -> loop() end` instead.

When spawning an anonymous function on a remote node, you also need to make sure that the module is loaded on both nodes, with the same version.  Otherwise you'll get a `badfun` error.

Comment: right, forgot the @localhost part, thanks. But, spawn(Node, Fun) docs(http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-2) say Fun has to accept empty list

Comment: also what is the point of Spawn(Node, Fun) if Node has to have the same module loadable? Why create illusion that you are sending a Fun to remote node to execute in a new process?  why not only spawn(Node, M, F, A) then?

Comment: The documentation talks about "applying" the function to the empty list — which means using the empty list as its argument list, i.e. passing zero arguments to it. As for why the module must be loaded on the other node, the usual case when using Erlang distribution is that all nodes have the same code, and thus you'd normally just send across a reference to the function. The difference between `spawn(Node, Fun)` and `spawn(Node, M, F, A)` is that the former can access variables in the function from which it was spawned.

Comment: @legoscia this post continues at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255471/what-is-the-point-of-spawnnode-fun-on-erlang-if-node-has-to-have-the-same-mo). I have posted a test that is not consistent with your last comment (in my mind). I also made some test where I call a module (ie maps) that was not previously loaded (checked with the m() shell function) and it works perfectly. So I think that some more accurate explanation should be added in the documentation