# What is the point of Spawn(Node, Fun) on erlang, if Node has to have the same module loadable as a client node?

Tags: erlang, distributed

Why create illusion that you are sending a Fun to remote node to execute in a new process? If client node has to have same module loadable with the Fun defined as a server node anyway. Why not only spawn(Node, M, F, A) then, which makes it clear that you are sending a definition of a function call, not Fun itself.

Answer (score 6):

Let's consider two possible cases

## Functions referring to module functions

```
Fun = fun file:getcwd/0,
erlang:spawn(Node, Fun).
```

In this case `Fun` indeed should be loadable at the remote side.

## Anonymous functions

```
Fun = fun() -> io:format("My node is ~p~n", [node()]) end,
erlang:spawn(Node, Fun).
```

They are *callable also*.

## Summarizing

While there some limitations implied to a function, that can be spwaned remotely, this form is still suitable and can be dropped, because then second case would become impossible

## Also

Some misconceptions might go from this [article](http://www.javalimit.com/2010/05/passing-funs-to-other-erlang-nodes.html)

Actually, if you run `erlang:fun_info` for anonymous function, you'll see, that it provides implementation in a form of AST

```
(b@lol4t0-home)21> rp(erlang:fun_info(fun() -> io:format("My node is ~p~n", [node()]) end)). 
[{pid,<0.96.0>},
 {module,erl_eval},
 {new_index,20},
 {new_uniq,<<99,62,121,82,122,95,246,237,63,72,118,40,4,
             25,16,50>>},
 {index,20},
 {uniq,52032458},
 {name,'-expr/5-fun-3-'},
 {arity,0},
 {env,[{[],
        {eval,#Fun<shell.21.31625193>},
        {value,#Fun<shell.5.31625193>},
        [{clause,1,[],[],
                 [{call,1,
                        {remote,1,{atom,1,io},{atom,1,format}},
                        [{string,1,"My node is ~p~n"},
                         {cons,1,{call,1,{atom,1,node},[]},{nil,1}}]}]}]}]},
 {type,local}]
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Yes anonymous funs are callable, what do you mean "also" callable. While I understand that firsts case (with module) is like a pointer to function. Second (anonymous) is a function object it self. My question is, why cant an anonymous function be sent to remote node to be executed. Why does it HAVE to be defined on a remote node?

Answer (score 2):

The example below shows that the remote node can execute a code that was never loaded on it, even a call to an anonymous function that was defined on the caller node:

on node titi

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
(titi@XXXXXXXX)1> net_adm:ping(toto@XXXXXXXX).
pong
(titi@XXXXXXXX)2> F = fun F(X) -> receive {plus,N} -> F(X+N); get -> io:format("state is ~p~n",[X]), F(X); stop -> bye end end. 
#Fun<erl_eval.30.52032458>
(titi@XXXXXXXX)3> G = fun() -> register(server,self()), F(0) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.52032458>
(titi@XXXXXXXX)4> spawn(toto@XXXXXXXX,G).
<7039.67.0>
state is 0           
state is 5           
state is 10          
(titi@XXXXXXXX)5>
```

on node toto

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
(toto@XXXXXXXX)1> server ! get. % will print state is 0
get
(toto@XXXXXXXX)2> server ! {plus,5}. % new state = 5
{plus,5}
(toto@XXXXXXXX)3> server ! get. % will print state is 5    
get
(toto@XXXXXXXX)4> server ! {plus,5}. % new state = 10
{plus,5}
(toto@XXXXXXXX)5> server ! get. % will print state is 10     
get
(toto@XXXXXXXX)6> server ! stop. % ends the server process    
stop
(toto@XXXXXXXX)7> server ! get. % message will fail
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  !/2
        called as server ! get
(toto@XXXXXXXX)8>
```

I also checked that if you replace the code `{plus,N} -> F(X+N);` by `{plus,N} -> F(maps:put(X,X+N,maps:new()));` which is calling a module not loaded by the shell at start, it works fine as well.

**Edit**

Read the comments, it seems that doing the test in the shell is not the right way, 2 conclusions though:

- do not rely on the shell only to make verifications,
- there should be a way to execute on the remote node a code that was only known on the caller node since the shell can do it...

Comment: As I understand it, functions defined in the shell are treated specially, so this might not work if the function was defined in the module.

Comment: @legocia : You are right, I made the test inside a module, it works only if the beam file is in the path of the remote node, with the same version. Thanks!