# Is there a way to send a closure to remote node in erlang?

Tags: erlang, distributed

It seams erlang only sends fun references to remote nodes. when trying to send closure, it apparently inlines closure in the calling module and sends a fun ref to that inlined fun to remote node. Here's the test:

```
-module(funserver).

-compile(export_all).

loop()->
receive {From, ping} ->
        error_logger:info_msg("received ping from ~p~n", [From]),
        From ! pong,
        loop();
    {From, Fun} when is_function(Fun) ->
        error_logger:info_msg("executing function ~p received from ~p~n", [Fun, From]),
        From ! Fun(),
        loop();
    M -> 
        error_logger:error_msg("received ~p, don't know what to do with it", [M])
end.
```

and the test on the client node:

```
test_remote_node_can_execute_sent_clojure()->
    {ok, ModName, Binary} = compile:file(funserver, [verbose,report_errors,report_warnings, binary]),
    {module, ModName} = rpc:call(?other_node, code, load_binary, [ModName, atom_to_list(ModName), Binary]),
    Pid = spawn(?other_node, funserver, loop, []),
    OutVar = {"token with love from", node()},
    Pid ! {self(), fun()-> {OutVar, erlang:node()} end},
    receive Result -> 
        Result = {OutVar, node(Pid)}
    after 300 ->
              timeout
    end.
```

getting

```
Error in process <7162.123.0> on node servas@sharas with exit value:
{undef,[{#Fun<tests.1.127565388>,[],[]},
        {funserver,loop,0,[{file,"funserver.erl"},{line,12}]}]}
timeout
```

So can clojure be sent to remote node?

Comment: Wasn't this already thoroughly discussed in [this thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-September/090046.html) in the erlang-questions mailing list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the point of Spawn(Node, Fun) on erlang, if Node has to have the same module loadable as a client node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255471/what-is-the-point-of-spawnnode-fun-on-erlang-if-node-has-to-have-the-same-mo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your example is that the client node compiles and sends the `funserver` module to the remote node - but that module is already there and executing, waiting to receive a message - but it doesn't send the `tests` module, which is the module that actually contains the fun you're sending across.

In the `compile:file` line, change `funserver` to `tests`, and it should work.

---

Also, you could use `code:get_object_code` instead of `compile:file`, since the module is already compiled and loaded in the local node.